# How to make column get taller with other columns

Tags: css

I am attempting to make a second column in a DIV get taller when the column next to it gets taller.

In an attempt to 'sterilize' what I was trying to do, I created the following HTML with the styling in the DIV tags.

```
<body style = "width: 100%;">
    <div style = "position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
        <div style = "display: inline-block; width: 700px; 
                     background-color: #ff0000; float: left;">
    line
     <br/>
    line
    <br/>
    line
    <br/>
    line
    <br/>
    line
        </div>
        <div style = "width: 300px; height: 100%; 
                      background-color: #000; float: left; color: #fff;">
    line
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

(There are a couple of closing tags I can't seem to get formatted correctly in this message.)

In my project, the red box can change height because the data inside will grow and shrink after the page has been loaded. So I have set it with display: inline-block.

When you display this, it will show one red area that fills the area from top to bottom. And there is a black side that only goes down one line.

How can I get the black side to go to the bottom AND shrink and grow with the red column?
I need the black box to extend to the same height as the red box.

Comment: I'd use javascript/jquery for this `$('div#two').height($('div#one').height()); `

Comment: You're missing a closing DIV tag for the wrapper in your code example.

Comment: Yes. I did think of that. But It seems this should work. The black column is set to height: 100%, and, according to the feed back from the element inspector, the enclosing DIV is as tall as the red DIV. So if it is possible to do with CSS, I'd rather do it that way.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post; I was not able to get the message formatted correctly, and there are some closing DIVs missing.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss You should never use `height:100%;`, check this article http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm

Comment: I think you misunderstood the article if you think you should never use height: 100%. It is just telling how to use it correctly. After reading the article, I can see there probably is no CSS solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to find the largest div/element and set the others to be the same size, which is a dynamic solution just in case the first div gets larger, jQuery will always set them to be the same height.

```
var maxH = 0;
$('div.column').each(function() {
  maxH = Math.max(maxmaxH, $(this).height());
}).height(maxH);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful:

http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

[Pure CSS solution for equal column height with stacked divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737499/pure-css-solution-for-equal-column-height-with-stacked-divs)